Regex match only if odd number of a character precede and follow
I want to match the closing quote together with the opening quote of the following string if both are on the same line. Two strings may be separated either by a blank   or a blank-plus-blank  + .
Regex engine: Python
F.i. from
this is "some string" "; which should match" 234
"and this" + "should also match\"" "\"and this" 
but not this: " " a " + "

I'd like to see matches for:

line 1: " " from between some string and ; which...
line 2:

" + " from between and this and should also match\"
" " from between should also match\" and \"and this


line 3: No matches

So in fact, I think it might be best to only match the groups " " and " + " if there is an odd number of quotes before and after the group. Since lookbehing/ahead is fixed length only, I didn't find a good way to do it.
I tried
re.compile(r'(" \+ ")|(" ")(?!;|,)')

but this assumes that there may be no semicolon within a string
and also
re.compile(r'"[^"]+")

but this only finds the strings themselves, but not the "inter-string" quotes.

This is not something that regular expressions are good at by themselves. You can split the string using "(?: | \+ )" as the delimiter, then check whether any of the pieces contain "

What kind of data do you have, where does it come from?

See if this works: https://regex101.com/r/WueRut/1 i.e. "[^"\\\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\n]*)*"(?: (?:\+ )?"[^"\\\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\n]*)*")+

But we need more details in question and some sample code. What are you trying to do with this regex?

You would be better served by writing a state machine that loops over the string  character by character.  You can track an "inside quotes" flag and count characters until the next open.

"Since lookbehing/ahead is fixed length only": note that look-ahead is not fixed in length.

Here's the character loop parsing method I mentioned above.  I track whether we are inside a quote or not, and I track the characters between quotes.

data = """\
this is "some string" "; which should match" 234
"and this" + "should also match\\"" "\\"and this" 
but not this: " " a " + "
"""

def check(line):
    in_quotes = False
    between = "xxxx"
    found = []
    escape = False

    for c in line:
        if escape:
            escape = False
        elif c == '"':
            if not in_quotes and between in (' ', ' + '):
                found.append( between )
            between = ""
            in_quotes = not in_quotes
        elif c == '\\':
            escape = True
        elif not in_quotes:
            between += c
    return found

for line in data.splitlines():
    print(line)
    matches = check(line)
    print(matches)

Output:
this is "some string" "; which should match" 234
[' ']
"and this" + "should also match\"" "\"and this" 
[' + ', ' ']
but not this: " " a " + "
[]


Thanks! It turned out an implementation based on your "state machine" was working very well and is still quite readable/understandable.


So in fact, I think it might be best to only match the groups " " and
" + " if there is an odd number of quotes before and after the group.
Since lookbehing/ahead is fixed length only, I didn't find a good way
to do it.

If you use re.finditer then you might use .start() and .end() to detect where it does start and end which allows you to get substring and count character, consider following simple example
import re
text = 'uno " dos " tres " '
for m in re.finditer(r'\s"\s', text):
    before = text[:m.start()]
    print("Match starting at", m.start(), "and ending at", m.end(), "has", before.count('"'), "quotes in front")

gives output
Match starting at 3 and ending at 6 has 0 quotes in front
Match starting at 9 and ending at 12 has 1 quotes in front
Match starting at 16 and ending at 19 has 2 quotes in front

In your you would need to split your text in lines before applying this solution.

I would indeed suggest to match pairs of (unescaped) quotes and the part that follows it. With a little lookahead you can also put the next character in a capture group, so you can check that it is a quote (and not the end of the line).
Here is an implementation:
import re

def get_matches(s):
    return (
        m.span(1)
        for m in re.finditer(r'"(?:\\.|[^"\n\r])*"((?:\\.|[^"\n\r])*)(?=("?))', s)
        if m.group(2) and m.group(1) in (' ', ' + ')
    )

This generator returns spans, so you get the location of where the match occured.
Run as follows:
s = """\
this is "some string" "; which should match" 234
"and this" + "should also match\" " "\"and this" 
but not this: " " a " + "
"""

for start, end in get_matches(s):
    print(f'{start}:{end} = "{s[start:end]}"')

Output:
21:22 = " "
59:62 = " + "
81:82 = " "

